# Remove .txt extension from all subfolders

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, batch-rename

Is it possible to create a batch file that removes all instances of .txt extension appearing? I tried the following, but it doesn't work for me.

```
for f in *.txt; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: this looks like ***BASH*** and not ***BATCH***.  Please give more specifics.  We can certainly help you.

Comment: I'm completely new to scripting, so I'm probably wrong. I just need a batch file to remove .txt extension from all files in a folder's subfolders. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a dangerous command indeed.. willy nilly renaming things in a tree like this..  If misused, it will leave you unhappy.

This is a simple batch file that uses functions to accomplish what you ask.
You will find an `echo` command on the rename line so you don't accidentally rename things that you don't want renamed.  When ready, delete `echo` and let 'er rip.

This could have also have been done using no function and the `EnableDelayedExpansion` command (but I don't like it).  I find the function syntax more readable.

```bat
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b *.txt') do call :rename_textfile "%%f"
goto :EOF

:rename_textfile
:: remove the echo command below when it works like you want it to.
echo rename "%~1" "%~dpn1"
goto :EOF
```